# Как откатить секвенцию в PLSQL в нужное значение?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Использую секвенцию для нумерации строк. Время от времени надо переинициализировать секвенцию чтобы отсчитывалось от другого значения.

Пробую так:

```
DECLARE
  V_TEMP_NUM number(9) :=0;
BEGIN
  V_TEMP_NUM := 15 - SEQ.CURRVAL;
  ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ INCREMENT BY V_TEMP_NUM;
  SELECT SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO V_TEMP_NUM FROM DUAL;
  ALTER SEQUENCE SEQ INCREMENT BY 1;
END;
```

Но выдаёт ошибку на `ALTER`. Как быть? Вообще ошибка на любые команды `ALTER`, `DROP` или `CREATE` внутри блока PL/SQL.

Как выполнить эти команды внутри блока?

Comment: [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Зачем вам нумеровать таблицы? А номера столбцов в поле `COLUMN_ID` системной таблицы `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` вам не подойдут?

Comment: @Dmitry, виноват, о своем задумался. Нумерую я, конечно, строки. Просто в них содержится инфа про столбцы таблиц, которые динамически будут созданы позже. А так-то, конечно, ID раздаются строкам.

Comment: Честно говоря, так еще менее понятно. DDL команды в PL/SQL можно выполнять только через `execute immediate`, но когда вы делаете столько динамических запросов (изменение последовательностей, а потом у вас еще динамическое создание столбцов намечается), скорее всего, вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: @Dmitry игнорируйте то, зачем мне нужна эта таблица в будущем, это не существенно, я убрал это из вопроса. Суть очень простая: я беру значения из последовательности и время от времени нужно задавать ей конкретное значение.

Comment: Вы делаете изначально что-то не то. Откат секвенций это экстраординарная ситуация, для разрешения которой базу переводят в ограниченый режим. Т.е.  "Время от времени надо переинициализировать секвенцию",  значит, что время от времени вы допускаете ошибку.

Comment: @0xdb мне просто нужно накатить некоторый профиль данных с инсертами. В общем вроде бы справился. Создал последовательность до plsql блока, а внутри последовательности скидывал через execute immediate перед заполнением каждой новой таблицы (меняя шаг на отрицательный и один раз шагнув, потом возвращал обычный шаг). Теперь одним скриптом накатывается весь профиль таблиц, при этом мне не нужно хардкодить ID, указывая только формулы.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Может вам вообще секвенции не нужны? Сделайте функцию, которая расчитывает следующее значение.  Что заставляет вас использовать секвенции, если то, как они работают, вас полностью не устраивает?

Comment: А зачем давать конкретные значения последовательностям? Все, что от нее обычно требуется - выдавать уникальные возрастающие (ну или убывающие) номера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сбросить последовательноть без её пересоздания:

```
create sequence seq1 nocache nocycle;
declare 
    v int; 
begin 
    for i in 1..1000 loop v := seq1.nextval; end loop;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence seq1 restart start with 115';
    dbms_output.put_line ('currval='||seq1.currval||' nextval='||seq1.nextval);
end;
/
currval=1000 nextval=115
```

Опция `restart start with` доступна с 12.2 и **недокументирована** ([ALTER SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-A6468B63-E7C9-4EF0-B048-82FE2449B26D)).
Как и для всех недокументированых функций и расширений, **строго не рекомендуется** её использование в продуктивной БД.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж пошла такая пьянка )))

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 

v_int integer := 200;
v_ddl varchar2(512) := 'CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_2
  START WITH '||v_int||'
  INCREMENT BY 1';

begin

  execute immediate 'drop sequence sequence_2';

  dbms_output.put_line(v_ddl);
  execute immediate (v_ddl);


end;
```